# Python memory error with numpy and csv reader

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I am reading two large csv files which each have 315,000 rows and 300 columns.  I was hoping to read all of this in using python but am now running into memory issues at around 50,000 rows.  I have around 4GB of RAM and each csv file is 1.5 Gig's. I was going to try amazon's webservices but iF anyone has suggestions on optimization techniques of reading in the files, I'd love to save the money!

sample data of first 2/314,000 rows here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MhJ7rn5OujR19LLVYyUFF5MVE/edit?usp=sharing

I get the following errors in my Python (xy) Spyder console :

```
for row in getstuff(filename): (line 97)
for row in getdata("test.csv"): (line 89)
MemoryError
```

I have also tried to do the following as a comment suggested and still receive a memory error:

```
for row in getdata("train.csv"):                        
   data.append(row[0::])

np.array(data)
```

Code below:

```
import csv
from xlrd import open_workbook 
from xlutils.copy import copy 
import numpy as np
import time
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from numpy import savetxt
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from xlwt import *


t0=time.clock()
data=[]
data1=[]

count=0
print "Initializing..."

def getstuff(filename):
  with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    count = 0
    for row in datareader:
        if count<100000:
            yield row
            count += 1
        elif count > 100000:
            return
        else:
            return

def getdata(filename):
  for row in getstuff(filename):
    yield row


for row in getdata("train.csv"):
   np.array(data.append(row[0::]))


for row in getdata("test.csv"): 
   np.array(data1.append(row[0::]))


target = np.array([x[1] for x in data],dtype=object)
train = np.array([x[2:] for x in data],dtype=object)    
test = np.array([x[1:] for x in data1],dtype=object)
```

Comment: Any reason you are not reading the csv with `numpy.genfromtxt`?

Comment: By writing `np.array(data.append())`, it probably does not convert `data` to an `np.array`.Maybe you can try converting `data` just once outside the loop.

Comment: Mr Rumbalski, thank you for your response. I tried genfromtxt initially and ran into similar issues but will try once again.

Comment: seb, I tried to convert to np.array(data) outside of the for loop and received a memory error again

Comment: Is your data numeric?

Comment: it is not, it's a mix of numeric and letters like "A", "B", "NA". I later run the array through a for loop to convert to floating point numbers, like A=1.45677

Comment: Can you provide an example of the file? Do you know beforehand the number of rows? (you can always get that with `wc -l`)

Comment: David, I have not used the wc -l command before but will check it out.  I have uploaded a sample of the file to google drive and shared the urL in the post above.  This is a Kaggle dataset on kaggle.com (Liberty Mutual Fire Challenge)

Comment: If you are planning on making a random forest ensemble with this data, you might as well give up - that'll require a lot more than twice the size of the data in memory. 4GB won't be enough in any way.

Comment: banana, you are right. but what if i limit the size of the forest to maybe 20 trees? or what if I ran it on amazon web services with 16 GB of RAM? Is it worth trying?

Comment: @user2476810 why don't you do something like `a = np.genfromtxt('stack.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtyp
e=object)` and then extract the columns: `target = a[:,1]` and so forth...?